# adding events to default calendar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

i am trying to add the event to iPhone default calendar and the code is as follows

NSMutableString *startDateString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"11/20/2012 10:00 AM"];

NSMutableString *endtDateString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"11/20/2012  5:00 PM"];

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a"];


NSDate * startDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDateString];

NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endtDateString];


EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"TEST";
event.startDate = startDate;
event.endDate   = endDate;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];


[startDate release];
[endDate release];


if(!err)
{

    UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"Event Added successfully " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];

}


NSLog(@"error is %@",err);
```

}

the event is successfully adding but the problem is its not adding to event start date its just adding to jan 1st 2001 date all the events are adding to the same date only .

can any one please help me where i am getting wrong & i am using the iPhone 4s & iPhone 3gs with 5.1.1 version.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set DateFormat to dateFormatter like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Note: yourdateString should be according to dateFormatter

Comment: finally i found the issue the issue is with date format the issue is i used "HH" and "a" in the formatter instead  i have to use "hh" if i used "a". any how thanks for replaying me .